# Rails render_to_string using wrong format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am encountering a problem with `render_to_string` using Rails 3.2.18 in which the function is trying to render the wrong view format despite its `:formats` option being correctly set (so for example rendering the `kml` view when `:formats` is set to `text`).

---

#### TL-DR version :

If I call `render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'text', layout: false)` and then `render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'json', layout: false)`, the later renders `bar.text` instead of `bar.json`

---

#### Long version :

I have a `FoosControler` that uses `render_to_text` when its `bar` action is called. `bar` can respond to three formats : `text`, `json` and `kml`. Under my views, I have the three corresponding files `bar.text.erb`, `bar.json.erb` and `bar.kml.erb`. I also have three different tests, in which the controller is instantiated and the output of `bar` is tested for the different formats (so I am calling `FoosControler.new.bar(format)`).

If I run each of those tests independently, I have no problems at all. So :

```
render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'text', layout: false)
# => renders bar.text.erb


render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'json', layout: false)
# => renders bar.json.erb


render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'kml', layout: false)
# => renders bar.kml.erb
```

The problems start if I have more than one of these in my test suite. What happens is the following :

```
render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'json', layout: false)
# => renders bar.json.erb
render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'text', layout: false)
# => renders bar.text.erb
render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'json', layout: false)
# => renders bar.text.erb instead of bar.json.erb !
```

From the moment I rendered `bar.text.erb`, any call to `render_to_string` with the `json` format renders `bar.text.erb` instead of `bar.json.erb` like it is supposed to.

The same happens between `kml` and `txt` :

```
render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'text', layout: false)
# => renders bar.text.erb
render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'kml', layout: false)
# => renders bar.kml.erb
render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'text', layout: false)
# => renders bar.kml.erb instead of bar.text.erb !
```

I can't seem to understand why this problem happens, as the problem isn't linked to the views - they all exist and can be rendered as shown before. Even stranger, everything works if I force the format in the render instead of using the `:format` parameter :

```
render_to_string('foos/bar.text', layout: false)
# => renders bar.text.erb
render_to_string('foos/bar.kml', layout: false)
# => renders bar.kml.erb
render_to_string('foos/bar.text', layout: false)
# => renders bar.text.erb like it is supposed to
```

A few other precisions :
- It doesn't matter whether I use `formats: '<format>'` or `formats: ['<format>']`
- The problem happens regardless of whether I use the different `render_to_string` inside the same controller using a breakpoint or whether I simply call the sequence of `FoosController.new.bar(format)` in the test, so the following two give the same result :

```
FoosController.new.bar
    render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'kml', layout: false)
    # => renders bar.kml.erb
    render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'text', layout: false)
    # => renders bar.kml.erb instead of bar.text.erb !


FoosController.new.bar('kml')
# => renders bar.kml.erb
FoosController.new.bar('text')
# => renders bar.kml.erb instead of bar.text.erb !
```

Any idea what can cause this unwanted behavior ? Forcing the format like I did seems to patch the issue, but I'd still want to know what exactly is going on.

Comment: Leaving this as well, but the problem seems to have arisen when Rails was updated to 3.2.18. Sounds like a version-specific bug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your format option from this:

```
render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'text', layout: false)
# => renders bar.text.erb
render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'kml', layout: false)
# => renders bar.kml.erb
render_to_string('foos/bar', formats: 'text', layout: false)
# => renders bar.kml.erb instead of bar.text.erb !
```

To this:

```
render_to_string('foos/bar', :formats => [:text], layout: false)
render_to_string('foos/bar', :formats => [:kml], layout: false)
render_to_string('foos/bar', :formats => [:text], layout: false)
```

Comment: I can't believe the solution was so simple. I'm still perplexed as for why it doesn't work with the text version though... Guess a simple `to_sym` on my format will do the trick then.

Comment: @Hyruu It's not just because you were trying with a `String` but also because it's expecting an `Array`. The `formats` parameter is plural.